# How to create a new Album in IOS in react native?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I want to create a new album of my app name in IOS using react native. CamerRoll (react native core module) doesn't allow to create new album. Any help?

Comment: Have you found any solution ? I also need this.

Comment: Not yet....I haven't worked on this after that, may be currently present lib do help in that. Pls check.